# Accessing errors of 3D surface generation algorithm

Tags: spatial, error, interpolation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assessing error of a spatial interpolation algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16287/assessing-error-of-a-spatial-interpolation-algorithm)

This is a similar question to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16287/assessing-error-of-a-spatial-interpolation-algorithm) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/smoothness-of-a-surface).

I have a set of 3D points that are sampled from a terrain. The points have three components $x$, $y$, $z$. You can think of these points as the surveyor points that one collects from measuring a terrain for GIS purposes.

I have a few algorithms that take in this set of 3D points as the reference: the algorithms will then

1. decide on the mesh size
2. compute a polygonal mesh for the area of the convex hull of the input 3D points.

Now, given that I have a few algorithms for this,  is there anyway I can evaluate and compare the correctness of these algorithms? Is there any kind of formula that allows me to know which algorithms are better at generating the 3D surface? The two most intuitive criteria for the evaluation are:

1. How near the interpolated points are to the given input points
2. How smooth is the surface

I have no idea how to quantitatively define the above two, what do you think?

Comment: This question provides additional details for http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16287/assessing-error-of-a-spatial-interpolation-algorithm .  It would be best, then, to keep them the same.  You can edit your old question to include this new information.